# Calculating consecutive occurences in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, case, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a quick question in relation to windowing in MySQL

```
SELECT 
Client,
User,
Date,
Flag,
lag(Date) over (partition by Client,User order by Date asc) as last_date,
lag(Flag) over (partition by Client,User order by Date  asc) as last_flag,
case when Flag = 1 and last_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end as consecutive
FROM db.tbl
```

This query returns something like the below. I am trying to work out the number of consecutive times that the Flag column was 1 for each user **most recently**, if they had 11110000111 then we should take the final three occurences of 1 to determine that they had a consecutive flag of 3 times.

I need to extract the start and end date for the consecutive flag.

How would I go about doing this, can anyone help me :)

[image]

If we use the example of 11110000111 then we should extract only 111 and therefore the 3 most recent dates for that customer. So in the below, we would need to take 10.01.2023 as the first date and 24.01.2023 as the last date. The consecutive count should be 3

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please show what results you want in your 11110000111 case

Comment: in that instance I just was 111 and the dates associated to them (i.e. the last 3 dates)

Comment: Please edit your question and show the rows and columns you would want

Comment: Also for 0110 .

Comment: Still not clear what you want actually returned.  Please show that

Comment: If the last flag for a user/client is 0, do you want nothing returned, or the last consecutive 1 flags?

Comment: If the last flag is 0 the we should not have a first date, last date or consecutive - they should all be null :)

Comment: So you want a row returned for each user/client combo even if they have no 1 flags?

Comment: Yeah exactly! I need to show every client/user but if there are no consecutive dates, then that's OK - we still show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and string functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Client, User,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Flag THEN Date END ORDER BY Date) AS dates,
         CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Flag ORDER BY Date SEPARATOR ''), '0', '-1')) AS consecutive
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Client, User
)
SELECT Client, User,
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dates, ',', -consecutive), ',', 1), '') AS first_date,
       CASE WHEN consecutive > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(dates, ',', -1) END AS last_date,
       consecutive 
FROM cte;
```

Another solution with window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
WITH 
  cte1 AS (SELECT *, SUM(NOT Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Client, User ORDER BY Date) AS grp FROM tablename),
  cte2 AS (SELECT *, MAX(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY Client, User) AS max_grp FROM cte1)
SELECT Client, User,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Flag THEN Date END) AS first_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Flag THEN Date END) AS last_date,
       SUM(Flag) AS consecutive
FROM cte2 
WHERE grp = max_grp
GROUP BY Client, User;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xam43-Oh).

Answer (score 1):

Made an attempt to get the result with more simpler queries and here is my approach taking advantage of lastDate and lastFlag column too.

Run [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/a42tMLUy)

```
WITH eTT 
AS 
( SELECT Client, User, NULLIF(MAX(Date), 
  (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM tt t2 WHERE t1.Client=t2.Client AND t1.User=t2.User)) as endDate 
  FROM tt t1 WHERE LastFlag=0 OR LastFlag IS NULL GROUP BY Client, User
)
SELECT Client, User, 
(CASE WHEN MAX(endDate) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE MIN(Date) END) as first_date, 
(CASE WHEN MAX(endDate) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE MAX(Date) END) as last_date, 
(CASE WHEN MAX(endDate) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(endDate) END) as consecutive 
FROM tt LEFT JOIN eTT USING (Client, User) 
WHERE Date >= endDate OR endDate IS null GROUP BY Client, User;
```

**EDIT**

The original table doesn't have `LastDate` and `LastFlag` columns and were created using OP's initial query.

Since the method used is not apparantly supported but I get an impression that OP somehow manages to do that on their side.

Hence another cte called `tt` can be added before `eTT` containing that query.

Comment: There is no column LastFlag in the table. It is derived from the OP's query with LAG().

Comment: @forpas sorry didn't knew what lag() does and hence thought that was the original table. I guess I will have to make another cte for building that table too.

Comment: @forpas I am not sure if that OP's query is finalised since it is referencing `last_flag` (which is an alias column and hence doesn't exist yet) in `consecutive`.

Comment: You claim that you provide *more simpler queries* (compared to what?). But what you actually do is omit half of the code needed. This is not simpler, it is wrong.